# How to compare the datetime picker value with some folder name 

Tags: c#, .net, file, datetime, zip

I have a backup files in folder  path is like this C:\Folder

the files are like this in below image[image]

the file name like this...20111011 means today date 
                          095523 means time

and i have a date time picker and i have button when the user select the value in datetime picker and select the button ,

I need to compare the date time picker value with the file name stored in that folder , and then if date time picker value matches the part of the folder name `(backup-{this is part})`   i want to extract  zip file into the given folder ....

how can i get compare date time picker value with the folder name and extract the files in to given path ....

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, do you have any existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx#Y0) method used to get files from specific path.

Below code mentioned in link make changes in foreach loop as you need. This loop give you filename and you can compare it.

```
public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
{
    // Process the list of files found in the directory.
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
      Do work here which you need.
}
```

Check this link for [datetimepicker value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx)

Comment: i know that one but how to compare file name with datetiempicker

Comment: There is property named value in datetimepicker use that property and compare it.

Comment: Check this code to get only date from datetimepicker string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString(); Or you want to get whole value use string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.tostring();

Comment: @Ali.. I got bit confused how to get the filename like this .. backup-20111011095656 from this path  C:\folder would you pls suggest any one ..

Comment: First write above function into your code after that pass path into this function like ProcessDirectory("c:\folder") after that place breakpoint on foreach loop and for checking there file retrived in array check in it and then after that split filename with "-" and you get separate date then compare that date with datetimepicker date.

Comment: One thing more formatting of file date and datetimepicker shoud be same ok. For spliting check this code string[] getfiledate = filename.Split('-'); then check if(getfiledate.length >1){if(getfiledate[1]==datetimepicker.value){Do functionality in this section}}

Comment: many thanks ..would you pls give sample code for that that would be very greatful to me ,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4170/discussion-between-emaad-ali-and-errorcode105)

Comment: Come on chat for further help.

Comment: Well at the moment i don't have any sample code but i think i explained you each and everything here. For further come on chat.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to set the [DateTimePicker date-time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) properly in order to select both date and time.

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh mm ss";
```

Next I think you have to construct the file name by using the DateTimePicker.Value. Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you can ToString the DateTime to your required format.

For example...

```
DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
string fileName = string.Format("backup-{0}",dt.ToString(yyyyMMddHHmmss));
```

Not sure about your time format. If it is 12 hour use "H" and use "HH" for 24 hours. Look at [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for more examples. The rest won't be difficult...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file names using [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

When you have read them, you can extract their dates using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to parse the file date and time.

And then you just have to compare the file date and time with the value of your date picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
DateTime dateSelected = <date coming from the picker>;
string fileRequested = string.Format("backup-{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}",dateSelected.Year,dateSelected.Month,dateSelected.Day,dateSelected.Hour,dateSelected.Minute,dateSelected.Second;
```

Then you can use the answer from Emaad to get work with the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a it "hacky" - but it works.

```
        var dateToParse = "20111011095323";
        var date = new DateTime(int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(0, 4)),
                                int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(4, 2)),
                                int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(6, 2)),
                                int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(8, 2)),
                                int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(10, 2)),
                                int.Parse(dateToParse.Substring(12, 2)));
```

Comment: Why not DateTime.ParseExact(dateToParse, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)?

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sometimes someone's on the wrong track ... ;-)